# Numpy vectorize where element is tuple

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I'm trying to understand how np.vectorize works. I wanted to iterate through an array where each element was a tuple then modify each element in the tuple, but this does not seem to work.

```
arr = [(1,3), (9,12)]

def func(i):
    return (i[0]+1, i[1]+2)

vfunc = np.vectorize(func)
vfunc(arr)
```

This would be the expected output:

```
[(2,5), (10,14)]
```

Please help me understand why it doesn't iterate over each tuple, and how I would achieve this - without use of a for-loop.

Comment: numpy vectorize *is* a for loop, so if you are expecting some magic performance improvements by using it, be prepared to be disappointed.

Comment: And you problem isn't with `np.vectorize`, it is the input, which is a list of tuples and gets converted to a 2x2 numpy array

Comment: Read and reread the docs.  `np.vectorize` isn't as easy a function as novices think.  It passes scalar values to your function. Elements of `np.array(arr)`.  Delay learning `np.vectorize` - there are more useful things in numpy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
[func(i) for i in arr]
```

`np.vectorize`, even where it works is not faster.

Or

```
np.array(arr)+np.array([[1,2]])
```

for a true numpy 'vectorized' calculation, adding a (1,2) array to the (2,2) arr.

p.s.

`arr` is a **list** of tuples.  If you can construct an array of tuples, I'll revisit the problem.

### edit

We should have objected because you did not supply the error message!  Especially since you are trying to understand `vectorize`.

```
In [307]: np.array(arr)
Out[307]: 
array([[ 1,  3],
       [ 9, 12]])
In [308]: vfunc = np.vectorize(func)
     ...: vfunc(arr)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-308-61dee032d8f1>", line 2, in <module>
    vfunc(arr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 2163, in __call__
    return self._vectorize_call(func=func, args=vargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 2241, in _vectorize_call
    ufunc, otypes = self._get_ufunc_and_otypes(func=func, args=args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 2201, in _get_ufunc_and_otypes
    outputs = func(*inputs)
  File "<ipython-input-306-ab62cb78d2b7>", line 4, in func
    return (i[0]+1, i[1]+2)
IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.
```

The error occurs in your function because you are trying to index a **scalar variable**.  `i` is a number, not a tuple.

Testing my initial suggestions:

```
In [309]: [func(i) for i in arr]
Out[309]: [(2, 5), (10, 14)]
In [310]: np.array(arr)+np.array([1,2])
Out[310]: 
array([[ 2,  5],
       [10, 14]])
```

Or making a 2 element array:

```
In [311]: A = np.empty(2, object)
In [312]: A[:]=arr
In [313]: A
Out[313]: array([(1, 3), (9, 12)], dtype=object)
In [314]: A[0]
Out[314]: (1, 3)
In [315]: vfunc(A)
Out[315]: (array([ 2, 10]), array([ 5, 14]))
```

Compare this `A` with `Out[307]`. Very different arrays.

Another way to diagnose this is to add a print to the func.

```
In [317]: def func(i):
     ...:     print(i)
     ...:     return (i[0]+1, i[1]+2)
     ...: 
In [318]: vfunc = np.vectorize(func)
In [319]: vfunc(arr)
1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-319-62576075c0b8>", line 1, in <module>
 ...
IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.
```

`vectorized` pass the first element of `np.array(arr)`, not the first tuple of `arr`, the scalar `1`.

Applied to the object array:

```
In [320]: vfunc(A)
(1, 3)               # the documented trial call
(1, 3)
(9, 12)
Out[320]: (array([ 2, 10]), array([ 5, 14]))
```

Now we see it is passing tuples to the function.